# Making a form to update multiple Users at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a form that updates the values of multiple users with one submit button. Here's my (obviously misguided) attempt:

```
<h1>Set Days</h1>
<%= form_for User do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :all do |user_form| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span><%= user_form.label :name %></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <%= f.fields_for user.name do |user_form| %>
          <table class="days-table">
            <tr>
              <td>M</td>
              <td>Tu</td>
              <td>W</td>
              <td>Th</td>
              <td>F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><%= user_form.check_box :monday, {}, true, false %></td>
              <td><%= user_form.check_box :tuesday, {}, true, false %></td>
              <td><%= user_form.check_box :wednesday, {}, true, false %></td>
              <td><%= user_form.check_box :thursday, {}, true, false %></td>
              <td><%= user_form.check_box :friday, {}, true, false %></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error with this code:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<Class:0x007fdcda98dc08>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that specific error because, under the hood, Rails' [`form_for(record, options = {}, &block)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) will try to send a `to_key` message to the first argument.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you'll be better off with [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

Updating multiple records at once is not *RESTful*.

For example, with one record the convention is:

```
PATCH  /resources/:id   { new data payload... }
# you're updating a specific resource
```

With multiple records you can't rely on a conventional REST endpoint, and need to let the server logic handle the process. For example:

```
POST /resources   { ids: [x, y, z], data: {...} }
```

So, build your form without associating it to a specific record (user `form_tag`, not `form_for`), and add to the POST request a list of IDs for the records you want to update.

Just **be careful** and take into account that this exposes you to attacks. What if a user decides to tweak the html of the form to update *other* records? You should use some authorization technique on the server side, or just not add that list in the form.

Then, on the server side, you can use something like this:

```
Resource.where(id: params[:id_list]).update_all(sanitized_params)

def sanitized_params
  params[:my_updates].your_sanitization_logic
end
```

Or, if your resources are already associated to the current user, this is a common pattern:

```
current_user.resources.where(id: params[:id_list]).update_all(sanitized_params)
```